# Laravel route regex

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I am trying to match url but can't figure out where I am wrong. I want to match urls like:
/{type}/{location}.{upper-case-iso-code}/name.

**Example: /hotel/paris.FR/belevue**

I tried using following expressions :

```
(.*\.])[A-Z]{2}
```

and

```
([]{1,}\.])[A-Z]{2}
```

Here is my route:

```
Route::get('/hotel/{city_hotel_link}/{hotel}', 'HomeController@hotel')->where...;
```

Comment: which part are you matching with given regex ?

Comment: I am matching city_hotel_link.

Comment: try to use this `[A-Za-z0-9]+\.[A-Z]{2}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this regex to separate location, dot, and city code:

```
(.*).([A-Z]{2})
```

so the first group will be location and the second will be city code.

Answer (score 1):

```
^[a-z]+\/[a-z]+\.[A-Z]+\/[a-z]+$
```

It matches

```
hotel/paris.FR/belevue
```

If the ISO code only has 2 characters:

```
^[a-z]+\/[a-z]+\.[A-Z]{2}\/[a-z]+$
```

Regex for city_hotel_link part only

```
[a-z]+\.[A-Z]{2}\/?
```